# Form post via PHP/Ajax from other domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

This is my form:

```
<!-- our form -->  
<form id='userForm'>
   <div><input type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='Firstname' /></div>
   <div><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Lastname' /></div>
   <div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></div>
   <div><input type='hidden' name='nl' vaule="1" /></div>
   <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>
```

...and this is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://www.otherdomain.com?param=XYZ', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#response').html(data);
        }).fail(function() {

           // just in case posting your form failed
           alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;
    });
});
```

When submitting this form via Ajax form my URL (which is NOT the goal-URL) I get a origin-error beacause of the cross-domain-policy. I can not edit anything in .htaccess.

So, is there an easy way to send the serialized data via JSONP to an PHP script which is submitting the data to avoid the origin-issue?

Hope that you had these problem too and help me with this.

Comment: Maybe in your ajax request, try adding crossDomain: true.

Comment: This does not work, I have tried this. thank you

Comment: ``crossdomain:true`` and ``dataType:jsonp``

Comment: well, this does not work. I know how post data via jsonp but I do not know how to handle the data with php and send them to the URL.